# C# VS C++: For IM Project

Tags: c#, c++

Our company will start a new project about IM. Currently we have a framework in C++ for IM. But someone thinks C# is better for the project. As I know, Yahoo ever started an IM in C# but gave up at last. Is there any idea about the prons and cons of C++ and C# for the IM project? We only care about windows platform.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can integrate the C++ framework with a C# front end.

Comment: Is this in-hourse or to be deployed to the world? If you use C# you need to worry about whether the end-users will have the right version of .NET installed (or whether they're willing to install it for your app?).

Comment: IM stands for Instant Messenger. It's deployed for the world and has old versions in C++. But there is a team in company who want to develop it in C# just because they are more familiar with C#. Here is the situation.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing specific to IM that is going to alter the C++ vs C# debate. The pros and cons will be the same as they are for any other project. You'll have to weigh the speed of development, the speed of bugfixing, the ease of finding developers, and the ease of deployment and come up with an answer.

Comment: IMHO for a Windows environment it will probably be easier (i.e. less time spent) developing, fixing bugs, and deploying with C#, though I suspect there are still more C++ developers out there.

Comment: @Jake: Whether this is true in the general case or not (and I, like you, suspect it probably is), user84983 must asses his specific case; he must determine his own situation (his company may already employ many more c++ developers than c# developers, for example) and come to a conclusion for himself.